# Calling function when scrolled element is fully visible in Angular ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic app that has a scrolling view like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts" >
  <div id="my-image-{{$index}}" is-visible><img src="post.img" /></div>
</div>
```

...and I want to trigger a function each time a new image is the active "fully visible" image. (Only one will fully fit.)

I was thinking of using something like this from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling/488073#488073):

```
  function isScrolledIntoView(el) {
      var elemTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      var elemBottom = el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

      var isVisible = (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight);
      return isVisible;
  }
```

But how do I get the id of the divs surrounding the images? Or is there a better way to accomplish this without jQuery?

UPDATE:
Tried this directive... but don't get anything in the console.

```
.directive('isVisible', function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function($scope, $element,$attr){
      var elemTop = $element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      var elemBottom = $element.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
      var isVisible = (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight);
      console.log($element);
      console.log("VISIBLE: " + isVisible);
      return isVisible;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Did you try writing a directive? You can use jslite inside and try the solution given in the other SO question.

Comment: @Roy - Trying but can't get directive to work...see updated question...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try ngInfiniteScroll, you can load any data once the window has reached the "end" of the current collection, it can be on the botton or the top too I think.
https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/